# MySQL, how to clone specific columns into new table?

Tags: mysql

I've a table consisting of 330 million values, with 970 columns. I need to drop 600 of them, so I've cloned the original, and wrote a script to drop one at a time. If my math is right this will take 18hours. Is there a way for me to specify column names and perform a clone of a table?

Something like....

```
CREATE TABLE table_clone LIKE table (Column.A, Column.B....etc);
INSERT table_clone SELECT Column.A, Column.B....etc FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ALTER TABLE` to remove all the columns at once:

```
ALTER TABLE table DROP col1, DROP col2, DROP col3, ...
```